# Thunderbird: font size when composing mails, whitespace between paragraphs and wrapping plain text

Tags: email, fonts, thunderbird

I use Thunderbird for mail now since half a year, and most of it is OK. One of the problems I have is when composing a new mail in HTML. In Apple Mail I could use RTF if I'm correct, and that worked a lot better. I don't know if it's HTML vs RTF, but the way Thunderbird handles font sizes and paragraphs is very irritating.

I start writing and the font size is small like I want it to be. Then I click on a button or do something else, then return to the mail, click below the text, and suddenly the font is bigger.

Another problem is with paragraphs. I write, start a new paragraph and use a double enter to create a white line. Then at times it changes and there is lots more whitespace between paragraphs.

It's not so much that I want one or the other, but I want it consistent. Why does the bigger font appear? If I make it smaller, then suddenly other things mess up. I hate this.

So I could use the plain text option. What I typically see from other people using Thunderbird and mailing me, is that when these mix with HTML mail (by replying to a plain text mail in HTML), the plain text doesn't wrap anymore. Another very irritating thing.

**So is there a way to get thunderbird working properly when writing and reading mail?**

Answer (score 0):

Menu Path:
[If running on Windows]: Tools | Options, or
[If running on OSX]: Thunderbird | Preferences, or
[If running on Linux]: Edit | Preferences
.. then Display | Formatting | Advanced
For "Monospace" choose the font and size you wish to use for plain text messages (and monospaced text in html messages) here.

For plain text this is truly a display option, not a composition option, as there will be no size encoding sent along with the message when transmitted.

http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=39&t=2429543